# Conditional Probability $10$ boxes with coins, $k^{th}$ box has a prob $1/k$ of landing heads

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Question

---

> There are 10 boxes in front of me, the $k^{th}$ box contains coins that lands heads with probability $\frac{1}{k}$ when flipped.
>
> > I pick a random box, then a coin from the box and flip it. The coin lands heads. What is the probability that it was from the first box?
> >
> > I do it again, and it lands heads again. What is the probability that it was from the first box?
> >
> > I do it again, and it lands heads again. What is the probability now that it is from the first box?

**My Attempt At a Solution**

Let $F$ be the event that the coin is from the first box. $P(F)=\frac{1}{10}$.

Let $K$ be the event that the coin is from the $k^{th}$ box. $P(K)=\frac{1}{10}$.

Let $N$ be the event that the coin is from the first box. $P(F)=\frac{4}{5}$.

Using the definition of conditional probability: $$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}  $$

$$P(F|H)=\frac{P(F \cap H)}{P(H)} =\begin{cases} \frac{\frac{1}{10}\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{1}{10} \quad \text{ for a fair coin} \\ \frac{\frac{1}{10}\frac{1}{1}}{\frac{1}{1}}=\frac{1}{10} \quad \text{ for an unfair coin with probability } \frac{1}{k}; k=1\end{cases} $$

$$P(F|(H\cap H))=\frac{P(F \cap (H\cap H))}{P(H\cap H)} \begin{cases} \frac{\frac{1}{10}\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{1}{10} \quad \text{ for a fair coin} \\ \frac{\frac{1}{10}\frac{1}{1}^2}{\frac{1}{1}^2}=\frac{1}{10} \quad \text{ for an unfair coin with probability } \frac{1}{k}; k=1\end{cases} $$

$$P(F|(H\cap H\cap H))=\frac{P(F \cap (H\cap H\cap H))}{P(H\cap H\cap H)}  \begin{cases} \frac{\frac{1}{10}\frac{1}{8}}{\frac{1}{8}}=\frac{1}{10} \quad \text{ for a fair coin} \\ \frac{\frac{1}{10}\frac{1}{1}^3}{\frac{1}{1}^3}=\frac{1}{10} \quad \text{ for an unfair coin with probability } \frac{1}{k}; k=1\end{cases} $$

So the probability is always $\frac{1}{5}$?

Thank you for any help/hints and your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have calculated the denominator incorrectly.  We must divide by the total probability that heads was obtained from *any* of the boxes that could have been selected.

Let's define our variables as follows:  Let $B_k$ be the event that the ball is from the $k$th box, $1 \leq k \leq 10$.  Let $H$ be the event that the coin lands heads.

Since the box from which the coin is extracted is chosen at random,
$$\Pr(B_k) = \frac{1}{10}, 1 \leq k \leq 10$$
Since the probability that a coin from the $k$th box lands heads is $1/k$, 
$$\Pr(H \mid B_k) = \frac{1}{k}, 1 \leq k \leq 10$$

The probability that the coin is from the first box given that it lands heads is 
$$Pr(B_1 \mid H) = \frac{Pr(H \cap B_1)}{\Pr(H)}$$
where $\Pr(H)$ is the total probability that heads was obtained from *any* of the boxes that could have been selected.  Therefore,
\begin{align*}
Pr(B_1 \mid H) & = \frac{\Pr(H \cap B_1)}{\Pr(H)}\\
               & = \frac{\Pr(B_1)\Pr(H \mid B_1)}{\sum_{k = 1}^{10} \Pr(B_k)\Pr(H \mid B_k)}\\
               & = \frac{\frac{1}{10} \cdot 1}{\sum_{k = 1}^{10} \frac{1}{10}\frac{1}{k}}\\
               & = \frac{\frac{1}{10}}{\frac{1}{10} \sum_{k = 1}^{10} \frac{1}{k}}\\
               & = \frac{1}{\sum_{k = 1}^{10} \frac{1}{k}}
\end{align*}

The probability that the coin is from the first box given that it lands heads on the first two throws is 
\begin{align*}
\Pr(B_1 \mid H \cap H) & = \frac{\Pr(B_1 \cap H \cap H)}{\Pr(H \cap H)}\\
                       & = \frac{\Pr(B_1)\Pr(H \mid B_1)\Pr(H \mid H \cap B_1)}{\sum_{k = 1}^{10} \Pr(B_k)\Pr(H \mid B_k)Pr(H \mid H \cap B_k)}\\
                       & = \frac{\frac{1}{10} \cdot 1 \cdot 1}{\sum_{k = 1}^{10} \frac{1}{10} \cdot \frac{1}{k} \cdot \frac{1}{k}}\\
                       & = \frac{\frac{1}{10}}{\frac{1}{10}\sum_{k = 1}^{10} \frac{1}{k^2}}\\
                       & = \frac{1}{\sum_{k = 1}^{10} \frac{1}{k^2}}
\end{align*}
I leave the calculations and the third part of the problem to you.

Comment: wow thank you, i was completely off, I understand now. I appreciate your time.